# Search for keyword directly from shell and get count without saving logs into external file

Tags: shell, unix

I'm executing my jar file which will create logs in the shell. My requirement is to search for a keyword,directly from the shell,without creating a log file.Executed using this code

```
`E:\Innoviti\BankInterfaceAumation>java -jar BankInterfaceAumation.jar 1`
Here is the logs
```

This is the logs created when I executed the jar

```
` 3:000000:000000 PASSED4:null:000000001600       FAILED
39:00:00        PASSED------------------------Response Conditions Passed----------------------------
AFter Sale terminal is null
2018-09-06 13:23:23 INFO  UniPayTerminalDataFetcherImpl:33 - Fetching unipay terminal with id
Cached terminal or after sale terminal is null/could not be fetched cached terminal is nullAfter sale txn bank terminal  null
 base transaction  is null/could not be fetched
Executing unipay terminal assertions  ********************************************

Test Scenario total_txn_amt null SAME null Passed
Comapring property key_exchanged_on value expression SAME
Comparing Simple Exrepssion property SAME
Test Scenario key_exchanged_on null SAME null Passed
Comapring property utid_state value expression 00
Test Scenario utid_state null 00  Failed
Comapring property key_exchanged value expression SAME
```

L00005022018090613231871319216803136 Failed`

The keyword = `Failed`

Comment: Provide the jar execution and sample logs with the keyword you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

You could "pipe" the log to:

```
 grep -o 'Failed' | wc -l
```

This will count the occourences of "Failed". If you need to search for case-insensitive the `grep` command becomes `grep -io`

Your command will become:

```
E:\Innoviti\BankInterfaceAumation>java -jar BankInterfaceAumation.jar 1 | grep -o 'Failed' | wc -l
```

If you want an example of execution you can try with:

`echo -e 'first line\nfailed Failed\nanother line with failed\nlast line' | grep -io 'failed' | wc -l`

An explanation of this command could be found here: https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=echo+-e+%27Some+Failed+text%27+%7C+grep+-o+%27Failed%27+%7C+wc+-l

Comment: Okay bro. I will check with this one. Thank you.